# Sql timestamp to Java date?

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I have a database which is going to have UMT timestamps in standard sql format.   How can I pull that data and set a java date object with it?

As far as I know mysql is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`   As for java, the date / time stuff has always eluded me.

If anyone knows of a good library for this I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't directly read it as `Date`

```
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp("date_field");

Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp("date_time_field");
```

**See**

- [`ResultSet.getTimeStamp()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: That is *NOT* safe for use in comparison with other instances of java.util.Date that are not actually a java.sql.Timestamp underneath.  A new java.util.Date should be made from the long value of the java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

A Timestamp is a subclass of a Date, which means it is usable everywhere where a Date is. The only difference is, Timestamp is more precise (due to the SQL specification) than Date is.

Just use:

```
Timestamp t = resultSet.getTimestamp("columnname");
Date d = t;
```

That having said, there are some benefits of converting the JDBC returned timestamp into a proper Date value, omitting nanoseconds. When you compare a Timestamp and a Date in some remote part of your app, the Timestamp and the Date won't be equal, even though they seem to be "rougly" the same time value. So if this could cause problem, create a new Date instance using only the .getTime() value returned by Timestamp)

More on this in my blog: [Timestamp and Date equality when using Hibernate](http://www.istvandevai.com/2012/05/timestamp-and-date-equality-when-using.html)

(even though the blog entry is about Hibernate, it applies to your case as well)