# How to sort a hasmap in java?

Tags: java, dictionary

This is my hashmap  :

`Map<String,String> unsortMap = new HashMap<String,String>()` this map contains values like follows

```
unsortMap.put("18/06/2012", "18/06/2012");
unsortMap.put("19/06/2012", "19/06/2012");
unsortMap.put("20/06/2012", "20/06/2012");
unsortMap.put("26/06/2012", "26/06/2012");
unsortMap.put("27/06/2012", "27/06/2012");
unsortMap.put("04/07/2012", "04/07/2012");
unsortMap.put("13/07/2012", "13/07/2012");
unsortMap.put("29/06/2012", "29/06/2012");
```

the code that i use to sort this map is as follows :

```
package samples;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SortMapExample{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Unsort Map......");
    Map<String,String> unsortMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    unsortMap.put("18/06/2012", "18/06/2012");
    unsortMap.put("19/06/2012", "19/06/2012");
    unsortMap.put("20/06/2012", "20/06/2012");
    unsortMap.put("26/06/2012", "26/06/2012");
    unsortMap.put("27/06/2012", "27/06/2012");
    unsortMap.put("04/07/2012", "04/07/2012");
    unsortMap.put("13/07/2012", "13/07/2012");
    unsortMap.put("29/06/2012", "29/06/2012");

    Iterator iterator=unsortMap.entrySet().iterator();

        for (Map.Entry entry : unsortMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted Map......");
        Map<String,String> sortedMap =  sortByComparator(unsortMap);

        for (Map.Entry entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }
   }

   private static Map sortByComparator(Map unsortMap) {

        List list = new LinkedList(unsortMap.entrySet());

        //sort list based on comparator
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
             public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
               return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
               .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
             }
    });

        //put sorted list into map again
    Map sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
         Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
         sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
   }    
}
```

The result i get is this:

```
Sorted Map......
Key : 04/07/2012 Value : 04/07/2012
Key : 13/07/2012 Value : 13/07/2012
Key : 18/06/2012 Value : 18/06/2012
Key : 19/06/2012 Value : 19/06/2012
Key : 20/06/2012 Value : 20/06/2012
Key : 26/06/2012 Value : 26/06/2012
Key : 27/06/2012 Value : 27/06/2012
Key : 29/06/2012 Value : 29/06/2012
```

I want the result to be like the following : (the map should be sorted based on the month also)

```
18/06/2012
19/06/2012
20/06/2012
26/06/2012
27/06/2012
29/06/2012
04/07/2012
13/07/2012
```

Pleas help me how to about this?

Comment: Any reason you are not working with java.util.Date instead of String?

Comment: This is probably not what you want to hear, but I couldn't resist: if you sort on strings, you should use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), little endian is superbad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your data to a SortedMap, specifically a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instance.

Use the constructor that takes a Comparator and within that, do your comparison logic.

Answer (score 4):

[`parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) the `String` to `Date` and then compare two date instance instead of `String`

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668696/parsing-from-string-to-date) to convert `String` to `Date` , now once you have date instance, it already implmentes comparator you could simple use

```
return dateInstance1.compare(dateInstance2)
```

in your comparator

**Note**: if you are reading these dates as String from database then [please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056119/sql-timestamp-to-java-date/11056134#11056134)

Comment: @Tony What is there to explain? Parse the date, compare on the date. Otherwise write a custom multi-field comparator.

Comment: with your current approach it just compare String chronologically which is not the actual comparison for Date

Comment: @JigarJoshi - you mean lexicographically rather chronologically.  He needs to **change** the string comparison to be chronological; i.e. in time order.

Answer (score 4):

Since `HashMap` is unordered. You should use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`. And you also need to parse `String` to `Date` for compare it.

Detail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: dates are stored in database as i explained above.(String)

Comment: with TreeMap custom comparator needs to be passed

Comment: @JigarJoshi That is also need to do.

Comment: @plucury - This is true, but if you read the code, you will see that Tony is already using a LinkedHashMap to represent the sorted Map.

Answer (score 3):

You are sorting Strings and the default behaviour for strings is to sort in ASCIIbetical order.

If you want to sort the keys in some other manner you need to convert them to the type you really want them to be (in this case dates)

Using SimpleDateFormat to convert the keys to Date object and compare those.